# Add the same event handler to radio buttons and checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, radio-button

I am trying to have a function add the values of selected check boxes and radio buttons.  I have created a function that can add the values of the check boxes and a function for the radio buttons but am having trouble combining the two into one working function.  I think my issue is with having both radio and checkbox elements associated with the `.click()`

My code can be seen here:
https://jsfiddle.net/Buleria28/nz43u7x8/2/

The HTML is:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" />test 1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="2" />test 2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="3" />test 3<br/>

<input type="radio" name="test" value="1" />test 4
<input type="radio" name="test" value="2" />test 5
<div id='sum'></div>
```

The jQuery is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var sum = 0;

$("input:checkbox"),$("input:radio").click(function() {
   sum = 0;
    $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function(idx, elm) {
        sum += parseInt(elm.value, 10);
    });

   sum = 0;
    $("input:radio:checked").each(function(idx, elm) {
        sum += parseInt(elm.value, 10);
    });
    $('#sum').html(sum);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/nz43u7x8/5/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var sum = 0;

    $("input:checkbox, input:radio").click(function() {
        sum = 0;
        $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function(idx, elm) {
            sum += parseInt(elm.value, 10);
        });

        $("input:radio:checked").each(function(idx, elm) {
            sum += parseInt(elm.value, 10);
        });
        $('#sum').html(sum);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're actually using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) and only adding the event handler to the second jQuery object. Instead combine the actual selectors by using a comma in the jQuery constructor's first argument, similar to a CSS selector:

```
$("input:checkbox, input:radio").click(function() {
  …
});
```